# How to (dis)prove the following about harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I've been asked the following and really don't know where to start...

Prove or disprove the following: 
If $u$, $v \colon \mathbb{R^{2}} \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions and $v$ is a harmonic
conjugate of $u$, then $u$ is a harmonic conjugate of $v$ (in other words, show whether or not the relation of being a harmonic conjugate is symmetric).

Can someone please explain (simply) what exactly defines a harmonic function / how you test a function is indeed harmonic and hence what a conjugate is? Then how would you complete the above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, please can someone tell me how to mathematical tell if a function is analytic and what it means to be analytic? Thanks

Comment: A function $u$ is called harmonic if $\Delta u=0$, namely if $\partial_1^2 u + \partial_2^2 u=0$.

Comment: What's mean harmonic conjugate?

Comment: And two functions $u$ and $v$ are harmonic conjugate if $u + iv $ is holomorphic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate

The article also answer your question.

Comment: okay thanks for the help guys, but I don't quite understand a few things: how can the change in u be 0 of a function, what is the quantity "partial 1 squared u" etc.
And also, I've revise the definition of holomorphic, and it's not helping:
We say that f is holomorphic at z if and only if there is an open set O ⊆ E such
that z ∈ O and such that f is differentiable at w for every w ∈ O.

Comment: Also, how do you use symbols such as delta, and partials and subscripts and superscripts? I'm new to math stackexchange

Comment: Siminore means $u$ is a function of two variables, ie $u = u(x_1,x_2)$. The quantity $\partial_1^{2}u$ means the second partial derivative of $u$ with respect to the variable $x_1$. Use this to get to grips with latex http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference